# How to Pass value to Non Nested components in Vue 3 composition Api

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I have a MainLayout , SideBar Component and a TopBar Component.
I placed a SideBarButton Component on the the TopBar Component, which when clicked should toggle the sidebar.

How do i pass the ref variable of SideBarButton to the SideBar Component?

```
MainLayout.vue
<template>
        <el-header><TopBar /> </el-header>
        <el-container>
          <el-aside ><SideBar /> </el-aside>
        <el-container>
</template>
```

```
TopBar.vue
<template>
  <el-menu-item>
        <SideBarButton />
  </el-menu-item>
</template>
```

```
SideBarButton.vue
<template>
    <el-button @click="toggleCollapsed"/>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const isCollapse = ref(false)

const toggleCollapsed = (e) => {

      isCollapse.value = !isCollapse.value;

    };
</script>
```

```
SideBar.vue
<template>
<el-menu
    default-active="2"
    class="el-menu-vertical-demo"
    :collapse="isCollapse"
    @open="handleOpen"
    @close="handleClose"
  >
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

</script>
```

**How do i get the value of isCollapse in this SideBar Component?**
I have tried for inject/provide but it didnt work.
Also the SideBarButton Component and SideBarComponent are not parent and child components, so Props do not work.

Comment: The interaction should go through a common parent, i.e. MainLayout. "I have tried for inject/provide" - what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1: Using props and emits

Emit the value from SideBarButton to TopBar, re-emit to MainLayout, then use the value to set a prop on SideBar

**SideBarButton.vue**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits(['toggleCollapsed'])
const toggleCollapsed = (e) => {
  isCollapse.value = !isCollapse.value;
  emit('toggleCollapsed', isCollapse.value)
};
</script>
```

**TopBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <el-menu-item>
        <SideBarButton @toggleCollapsed="$emit('toggleCollapsed', $event)" />
  </el-menu-item>
</template>
```

**MainLayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <el-header>
    <TopBar @toggleCollapsed="isCollapse = $event" />
  </el-header>
  <el-container>
    <el-aside>
      <SideBar :isCollapse="isCollapse" />
    </el-aside>
  <el-container>
</template>

<script setup>
const isCollapse = ref(false)
</script>
```

**Sidebar.vue**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  isCollapse: {
    default: false
  }
})
</script>
```

[Vue Playground demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

#### Method 2: Using v-model and defineModel()

New in Vue 3.4, the [defineModel](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#definemodel) macro can now be used with v-model.  It's basically still doing the same job as setting up props and emits under the hood, but less code.

**MainLayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <el-header>
    <TopBar v-model="isCollapse" />
  </el-header>
  <el-container>
    <el-aside>
      <SideBar :isCollapse="isCollapse" />
    </el-aside>
  <el-container>
</template>

<script setup>
const isCollapse = ref(false)
</script>
```

**TopBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <el-menu-item>
    <SideBarButton v-model="isCollapse" />
  </el-menu-item>
</template>

<script setup>
  const isCollapse = defineModel()
</script>
```

**SideBarButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <el-button @click="value = !value"/>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const value = defineModel()
</script>
```

**SideBar.vue**

(same as Method 1)

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  isCollapse: {
    default: false
  }
})
</script>
```

[Vue Playground demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

It's not clear in your question whether **SideBar.vue** also needs to be able to set the value of `isCollapse`, but my code in both methods assumes it does not.  If it does, you can use the same strategies again with emitting the change back up to MainLayout or using v-model/defineModel again with SideBar.